# Jsf library with web.xml

Tags: java, jsf, web.xml, faces-config

Jsf library (that is included in WEB-INF/lib) might contain its own faces-config.xml file.

Is it possible for such a library to include also its own web.xml file?

Comment: I guess it cannot. Otherwise libraries as facelets or richafaces, who need configuration lines in web.xml would include this configuration in its own web.xml file, wouldn't them? It's just a guess, that's why I don't write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not until [Servlet 3.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html).

There you'll have "web fragments" (see under "Pluggability and Extensibility" from the above article)